# python or pythonw in creating a cross-platform standalone GUI app

Tags: python, user-interface, cross-platform

I am developing a simple standalone, graphical application in python. My development has been done on linux but I would like to distribute the application cross-platform.

I have a launcher script which checks a bunch of environment variables and then sets various configuration options, and then calls the application with what amounts to `python main.py` (specifically `os.system('python main.py %s'% (arg1, arg2...))` )

On OS X (without X11), the launcher script crashed with an error like `Could not run application, need access to screen`. A very quick google search later, the script was working locally by replacing `python main.py` with `pythonw main.py`.

My question is, what is the best way to write the launcher script so that it can do the right thing across platforms and not crash? Note that this question is not asking how to determine what platform I am on. The solution "check to see if I am on OS X, and if so invoke pythonw instead" is what I have done for now, but it seems like a somewhat hacky fix because it depends on understanding the details of the windowing system (which could easily break sometime in the future) and I wonder if there is a cleaner way.

This question does not yet have a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Are you averse to using something like PyInstaller? I find it generally makes cross platform distribution much easier as it bundles up all your library requirements and specific python version.

Comment: No I am not averse to using tools to make my life easier -- I am just clueless about cross platform distribution. Unfortunately it seems like nobody has gotten pyinstaller to work with a scientific python distribution (I am using canopy). Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you save the file as `main.pyw`, it should run the script without opening up a new cmd/terminal.

Then you can run it as `python main.pyw`

Comment: @aestrivex If you run it from terminal, it won't close the terminal you executed it from, but if you make it executable it should work (Although I admit, I'm not too familiar with using .pyw on Mac).

Compilers for python are definitely a bit lacking, and often take a bit of hacking to get it to work properly. Cx_Freeze is another good option, if you don't care about single file executables.

I haven't used canopy, so I can't say cx_freeze will work, but it's definitely worth trying.

Comment: I open the terminal and type `python main.pyw`. It returns the same error about "program needs to access screen run it with pythonw" on this OS X machine. I made the script executable too, it made no difference (I dont see why it should).

Comment: Having spent about the last hour messing with pyinstaller and py2exe, I agree that they are a bit lacking. The idea is a good one, but in this case it would be quite a lot of work to get the entire program packaged up correctly. For my specific program, it isn't unreasonable to ask the user to install a scientific python distribution anyway, I am really just looking for a way to write a launcher that can run the program cross-platform.

Comment: @aestrivex When you compile with pyinstaller, what errors are you getting? What GUI framework are you using? The more detail you can give, or even if you can give reproducible steps, the better.

Comment: My program is written in traitsui which uses `__import__` to determine the correct GUI backend at runtime. I tried to create a very stupid traitsui program showing a GUI with one integer field using the wx backend and provide hooks to pyface. Unfortunately the efforts made by pyinstaller to support GUI backends do not translate to pyface very well which uses its own image resources. So after getting some hooks to import properly, the compiled binary failed with errors like `NotImplementedError: ImageResource not found` and I realized the scope of fixing it was too large for my current project.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should always use `.pyw` for GUIs.

Secondly, you could convert it to `.exe` if you want people without python to be able to use your program. The process is simple. The hardest part is downloading one of these:

- for python 2.x: p2exe
- for python 3.x: cx_Freeze

You can simply google instructions on how to use them if you decide to go down that path.

Also, if you're using `messageboxes` in your GUI, it won't work. You will have to create windows/toplevels instead.

Comment: As noted in the other answer comment thread, using `.pyw` does not work on OS X. This question still does not have an acceptable answer.