# How to only allow Tkinter to open and not the command prompt?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to Python, and my code uses a "tkinter" GUI. Is there anyway for me to run this so that only the GUI is shown, and not the command prompt?

I know the extension .pyw suppresses the command prompt on start up, but when I use it the GUI doesn't appear either

Comment: These articles may be helpful. [How to open PYW files on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45976196/9014308), [How to hide console window in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/764631/9014308), [python or pythonw in creating a cross-platform standalone GUI app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23659248/9014308), [pythonメモ 　pythonw.exeの注意点](https://jkani4.hatenadiary.org/entry/20080122/1201003104)